# Need a quick way to process each line of a file using batch, without piping to echo

Tags: file, batch-file, process, echo

So I am using a batch to go through a text file line by line. The reason why I can't do a regular search is because I need to see what is written on each line and then determine how I want to process the next line. Anyway, my basic code is:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%SourceLicenseFile%) do (
    Set LineofFile=%%a
    echo !LineofFile! | find /i "TIMESTAMP" >nul
    if !errorlevel! EQU 0 ( 
        FOR %%b IN (!LineofFile!) DO SET LogDate=%%b
    )
    echo %%a | find /i "(LOGTIME) IN" >nul
    if !errorlevel! EQU 0 ( 
        FOR %%d IN (!LineofFile!) DO SET Username=%%d
        FOR /f "tokens=1" %%c IN ("!LineofFile!") DO (
            SET Logtime=%%c
        )
        echo !LogDate!  !LogTime!   !Username!
        >> !ExportLicenseLog! echo !LogDate!    !LogTime!   !Username!
    )
)
```

I believe the echo is slowing down this processing. I have a file with thousands of lines and it would take me over a minute to process. Is there another method I can use to go through each line quicker?

Comment: You should show a neutralized sample of your SourceLicenseFile to see the layout - so we can possibly come up with a better way.

Comment: Instead of reading the entire file by `for /F`, would prefiltering by `findstr` be an option for you? like: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /C:"TIMESTAMP" /C:"(LOGTIME) IN" %SourceLicenseFile%') do ( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `echo ... | find ...` slowdown the process, not because the `echo`, but for the pipe...

You have not clearly explained the purpose of your program. However, to check if `!LineofFile!` variable have the `"TIMESTAMP"` string, you may use this code:

```
if "!LineofFile:TIMESTAMP=!" neq "!LineofFile!" (
   echo TIMESTAMP string found in LineofFile variable
)
```

This code means: "Try to remove TIMESTAMP string from LineofFile variable. If the string was found, it was removed, so the replaced value is different than the original".

Comment: yup... seems like we posted the solution around the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the echo:

```dos
find /i "SOMETHING"<%SourceLicenseFile%
```

Escape thus **^<** inside a for parentheses.

Comment: Compo, thanks for the response. However, as I process the file, what I am doing in the for loop will change. For instance, line 47 may say "Test1" then I need to do "Action1" to line 48 and 49....etc. I can't just search the file for one thing. My code above is a stripped down version for this website. So I need to search for "Test1" and then set variables that will trigger different searches for lines 48 and 49 but could be reset later in the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Wajo357, then update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: @Wajo357 please put down all your requirements.

Comment: OK... I've updated the code to show the relevent parts for this batch file. However, I will be creating another batch file different requirements, but the same concept... where I need to go through the code one line at a time.

Comment: The basic theory above is that I need to show when users are accessing the software. The log file from the software has the date in random parts of the file and the user and time in other parts of the file. I am therefore going through the file and converting this nonsense to a simple date, time, username in another file that I can use in excel.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it. Using substitution is MUCH faster

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%SourceLicenseFile%) do (
    Set LineofFile=%%a
    if not "x!LineofFile:TIMESTAMP=!" EQU "x!LineofFile!" (
        FOR %%b IN (!LineofFile!) DO SET LogDate=%%b
    )
    if not "x!LineofFile:IN:=!" EQU "x!LineofFile!" (
        FOR /f "tokens=1,5" %%c IN ("!LineofFile!") DO (
            SET Logtime=%%c
            SET Username=%%d
        )
        if "!LogDate!" NEQ "DATE NOT FOUND" (
            echo !LogDate!  !LogTime!   !Username!
            >> !ExportLicenseLog! echo !LogDate!    !LogTime!   !Username!
        )
    )
    Set /A LineNumber=!LineNumber!+1
    Set /A PercentDone=!LineNumber!/%TotalLines%
)
```